# date.time not printing date AND time (within addSecs function)..... python 2.7

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, output

Hi does anyone have experiance with this date,time function, i feel like I'm missing something important.....
There is something weird going on when I print Date_time, if i print it by its self, like in the code below (first print output) i get both the date and the time. But when i print it as part of the addSecs function, i lose the date part...

```
############
DeltaTimeS = 9e-6
#########

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Date_time = datetime.strptime(T['value'], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')


print 'Date_time =',Date_time 


def addSecs(tm, secs):
    fulldate = datetime(100, 1, 1, tm.hour, tm.minute, tm.second)
    fulldate = fulldate + timedelta(seconds=secs)
    return fulldate.time()


for i, x in enumerate(Data_list):

    print ';'.join(map(str,["Hello",addSecs(Date_time, i * DeltaTimeS),x]))
```

output looks like this

```
Date_time = 2016-08-24 14:59:08
Hello;14:59:08.095733;-0.04821
Hello;14:59:08.095742;-0.05164
Hello;14:59:08.095751;-0.05134
Hello;14:59:08.095760;-0.04280
Hello;14:59:08.095769;-0.03390
Hello;14:59:08.095778;-0.02819
Hello;14:59:08.095787;-0.01727
Hello;14:59:08.095796;-0.00933
Hello;14:59:08.095805;-0.00435
Hello;14:59:08.095814;0.00273
Hello;14:59:08.095823;0.00924
Hello;14:59:08.095832;0.01594
```

I'm using the join function becuase the output need to be without spaces. Also this code is pulling the datalise from a database, so i dont think it will run for you. But maybe you can see the problem without running it????

Comment: Of course your `addSecs` function loses the date info, you told it to just return the time!  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit trashes the date information:

```
fulldate = datetime(100, 1, 1, tm.hour, tm.minute, tm.second)
```

And then this bit converts a `datetime` into a `time` structure (without date):

```
return fulldate.time()
```

Why don't you just do:

```
def addSecs(tm, secs):
    return tm + timedelta(seconds=secs)
```